# Save Data on iOS app. Using Marmalade 5.2

Tags: ios, save, marmalade

I'm going to need to update my iPhone app on the app store at some point.

I’m using secure storage functions (s3eSecureStoragePut) for save data that creates an appdata.i3d file.

When I update the app I want to preserve the players save data, how can I ensure this done?

Answer (score 2):

s3eSecureStorage is a bit misleading, it is not secure and this is a historical name related to the Brew and Symbian platforms. Essentially all this is doing is writing to a file so it will be preserved on app updates assuming you don't write over it.